# In Zend Framework 2, How to allow only unique inputs in email

Tags: zend-framework2

How do I allow only unique inputs in form for email as in gmail?.. not to allow duplicate email or already existing email in ZF2. Is there any inbuilt keyword or code for this query

Answer (score 3):

Google before you ask here dude!
You should use `Zend\Db\Validator\NoRecordExists` validator. Read the docs [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.db.html)

Comment: Keep in mind this one will not work with doctrine. And you would have to write the validator yourself.

Comment: @cptnk What?? Are you sure?? What about [this](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md)?